# hbase schema design for fast searching on many columns

Tags: search, indexing, hbase

I have to create a table consisting of 30 columns in Hbase , the problem is that I have 5 different queries running on 5 columns.The question basically is the table is having indexes on multiple columns in Oracle , how to use that in hbase.
All the 5 queries are sla bound.

What can be the possible approaches to start with.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the types of these 5 columns?

Comment: Out of 5 columns,
4 columns are of numeric type(6 ,10,10 and 16 digits resp.)
and  1 column is of  alpha numeric type